# correct architecture to consume message from another datacenter in apache kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

We have 2 different data centers DC1 and DC2. DC1 is active and DC2 is passive.
Now we have installed Apache Kafka in DC1 and created topics, wrote producers and consumers and able to push the data correctly from source to sink.
Now we have the following requirement.

- we need to keep the sink of DC2 also in synch with DC1. it means the data which is pushed to topic A by producer need to be consumed by two consumers. The first consumer which is already working is from DC1 itself and the other consumer has to be from DC2.

We thought of coming up with a solution like this

Create another consumer group in DC2 which listens to the same topic in DC1.
We are not sure on how it is going to work and how we can make DC2 consumer group listen to DC1 topic.
What is the correct way of handling it and morrow it is possible that DC2 can become active and DC1 be passive to handle DR.
We read on MirrorMaker tool but not sure on how to use it and is that the correct solution to address our problem statement.

Comment: Hi,
     You are correct. In case DC1 kafka fails then DC2 kafka should pitch in and play the lead role. They need to run in active / passive mode. 
We are going to have 1 kafka cluster setup in DC1 and similar one in DC2.

Are there any Kafka settings which need to be enabled to make one active and another passive?

we are using Kafka 0.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the key question here is

**Is DC2 full disaster recovery solution ?** ( 
I mean, in case DC1 kafka fails, should DC2 have all the data and resources needed to continue operation ) ?

Option 1 (prefferred) : **If the answer is YES**, I would set up two different kafka clusters for DC1 and DC2. And use the MirrorMaker tool to consume topics from DC1 into DC2.

Take into account that you might have topics with "intermediate" data in kafka and if you are running the same processes in parallel in the two DCs you could have *duplicate* data in that topics if you replicate them in Mirror Maker.

Be very careful with the processes to recover DC1. Probably the easiest way to do this is to have DC1 as a passive copy when DC2 is taking the lead and replicate then data to DC1 with MirrorMaker.

Option 2 (more complicated): **If the answer is NO, AND YOU ARE VERY DISCIPLINED / HAVE VERY STRICT PROCESSES and you AUDIT periodically/automatically your infrastructure** then you can setup kafka brokers with rack aware replication (setting broker.rack=DC1 or DC2) and the cluster will send replicas to the brokers in the second DC <-- BUT your kafka installation in DC2 won't be "passive" at all.

Caveat here: You must set up always a minimum of two replicas for each topic (to avoid mistakes put default.replication.factor = [number of different DCs you have] in your kafka broker config - but be aware that this can be overriden).

If you have kafka in different DCs, I would also assign Kafka broker IDs that reflect which DC every broker "lives". For instance, for DC2 I would start numbering brokers with the number "200" and for DC1 brokers should start with "100".

Comment: Hi, You are correct. In case DC1 kafka fails then DC2 kafka should pitch in and play the lead role. They need to run in active / passive mode. We are going to have 1 kafka cluster setup in DC1 and similar one in DC2. Are there any Kafka settings which need to be enabled to make one active and another passive? we are using Kafka 0.9.